# not show query anything in codeigniter

Tags: sql, postgresql, codeigniter

```
$time = strtotime('08/09/2017');

$a = date('Y-m-d',$time);

$this->db->select('gt.shiftkerja','gt.tanggal','i.jenis','i.konsinyasi','gp.group');
$this->db->from('tbl_ikhd gt');
$this->db->join('tbl_ikdt dt','gt.notransaksi=dt.notransaksi','left'); 
$this->db->join('tbl_item i' ,'dt.kodeitem=i.kodeitem','left'); 
$this->db->join('group_posting gp','gp.kode_group=i.jenis and gp.konsinyasi=i.konsinyasi','left');
$this->db->where('gt.tanggal', $a); 
$this->db->group_by('gt.shiftkerja','gt.tanggal','i.jenis','i.konsinyasi','gp.group');
$this->db->order_by ('gt.shiftkerja','gp.group');
return $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to include `result()`

```
 return $this->db->get()->result();
```

Comment: Call to a member function result() on null

Comment: Sounds like your query is failing. Add db debug to true in config and see if that helps find the problem.

Comment: Use `$this->db->get_compiled_select();die();` before `return $this->db->get()->result()` to check the query string and test it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Debug database level error in `codeigniter` using:

`var_dump($this->db->error());`

Clearly you have two errors:

1. In select statement must be:

   `$this->db->select('gt.shiftkerja, gt.tanggal, i.jenis, i.konsinyasi, gp.group');`
2. You have to return result either in object or array like below:

   `return $this->db->get()->result_array();//returns result in array format`

   OR

   `return $this->db->get()->result();//returns result in object format`